# Most performance-wise query for sum from two joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, left-join

I have 3  tables:

**customer**

```
id
name
```

**service_type1**

```
id 
customer_id 
price (one to many relation to the customer)
```

**service_type2**

```
id
customer_id 
price (one to many relation to the customer)
```

I would like to list these values: `name`, `service_type1 – sum price`, `service_type2 – sum price`

I created two queries which do what I want:

A:

```
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(price) AS sum_price,
    (SELECT SUM(price)
        FROM service_type2
        WHERE customer_id = u.id
    ) AS sum_price2 
FROM customer u
LEFT JOIN service_type1 a ON a.customer_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.id
```

B:

```
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(price) AS sum_price,
    p.sum_price AS sum_price2
FROM customer u
LEFT JOIN service_type1 a ON a.customer_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(price) AS sum_price, customer_id
    FROM service_type2
    GROUP BY customer_id
) p ON p.customer_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.id
```

I benchmarked them and their execution times are the same*. Is it possible to write more performance-wise queries?

* It isn't true. "A" is much faster with 30k+ records in each table.

Answer (score 1):

I might think that this version would work better with the appropriate indexes:

```
SELECT u.name,
       (SELECT SUM(st.price)
        FROM service_type1 st
        WHERE st.customer_id = u.id
       ) as sum_service_type1,
       (SELECT SUM(price)
        FROM service_type2 st
        WHERE st.customer_id = u.id
       ) as sum_price  
FROM customer u
ORDER BY u.id;
```

The best indexes are `customer(id, name)`, `service_type1(customer_id, price)`, and `service_type2(customer_id, price)`.

Comment: It was my first attempt and I tried two avoid from the two dependent  sub queries. By the way these 3 solutions are very close to together in performance.

Comment: @igoemon this doesn't avoid 2 sub queries, but it does avoid left joins which should help out some in the long run.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You probably meant to say `service_type1(customer_id, price)` on your second index recommendation? :)

Comment: @JamieD77 As I wrote this solution (which is also my first attempt) and my A and B version are very close together in performance.

Comment: @JamieD77 I tested with 30k+ records in each table and this query and the "A" query has the same performance, but "B" is much slower with this larger record set.

Comment: @FutbolFan . . . Yes.  I noticed the data layout in the text and the columns used in the OP's query were different.

Comment: @igoemon . . . The main performance gain is the lack of `group by` on the outer query and the use of the indexes for the aggregation in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, try this:

`SELECT id,sum_service_type1
INTO #T1
FROM service_type1
GROUP BY customer_id`

`SELECT id,sum_service_type2
INTO #T2
FROM service_type2
GROUP BY customer_id`

`SELECT
    name,
    sum_service_type1,
    sum_service_type2, 
FROM customer u
LEFT JOIN #T1 a ON a.id = u.id
LEFT JOIN #T2 b ON b.id = u.id`

to improve you can create a clustered index

Comment: unfortunately this would give you a SUM that is double what it should be if both service_type tables have 2 records.. i believe

Comment: It is wrong because the two the joins multiplies the rows and creates false sum values. (I would be perfect for one joined table.)

Answer (score 0):

How about run these two queries, and merge two result sets into one using merge sort in the client side. (They are already sorted by `u.id`, so that we can merge it easily).

```
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(price) AS sum_service_type1,
FROM customer u
    LEFT JOIN service_type1 a ON a.customer_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.id;

SELECT
    name,
    SUM(price) AS sum_service_type2,
FROM customer u
    LEFT JOIN service_type2 a ON a.customer_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.id;
```

I think if the sum of execution time of 2 queries is less than your query, it is affordable to implement in the client side.

Comment: You are right, but the pure sql solution is which is really interesting for me.

Comment: @igoemon I wonder whether you are using old version of MySQL. With MySQL 5.5 (I'm currently using) dependent subquery (A in your case) was slower than sub-query. In Addition, MySQL 5.6 has a materialization feature (I didn't tested yet) I hope this help you. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html#subquery-materialization